# How is FreeBSDs/DragonFlyBSD sendfile() system call supposed to work?

Tags: freebsd, system-calls, dragonflybsd

[sendfile()](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sendfile&sektion=2)

The `offset` argument is of type `off_t` and `nbytes` is of type `size_t` while both are describing the same thing: a file length. What if my file is longer than `off_t` but shorter than `size_t`? If I'm sending asynchronously it can happen that my current file offset is larger than `off_t`, but I still want to send more since `size_t` is greater.

`off_t` is always lower since it is signed and `size_t` is unsigned.

I know that you can set `nbytes = 0`, but I explicitly want to use a length.

Answer (score 1):

The `offset` and `nbytes` arguments are not describing the same thing. On the contrary, they're describing where to start and where to end copying bytes from the file, respectively.

If your file is 131,072 bytes in size (128KiB) and you use an `offset` of 16,384 and `nbytes` of 32,768, then `sendfile()` will copy from position 16,384 to position 49,152 on the file, for a total of 32KiB (specified by `nbytes`) starting at `offset`.

If you use an `offset` of 114,688 and `nbytes` of 32,768, then `sendfile()` will copy from position 114,688 to the end of the file, at position 131,072, for a total of 16KiB. Since the file was shorter than the expected `nbytes`, `sendfile()` will send less data than requested.

If you use an `offset` of 147,456 and `nbytes` of 32,768, then `sendfile()` will send 0 bytes. If the start is past the end of the file, there will be no bytes to copy, so it will just send nothing.

Finally, there's a special case for `nbytes` set to 0, which will copy the whole contents of the file, so if you use an `offset` of 0 and `nbytes` of 0, then `sendfile()` will send a total of 131,072 bytes (128KiB), for the whole file.